# start geth with poa

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-clique

to start geth with clique, i followed the geth docs example,

https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network

to 'Initializing the Geth Database' Chapter

But it didn't work, [image: my geth]

is there anything to add configuration to genesis.json more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a signer(validator) in your Clique network. So you need to create a signer with geth account new and set it coinbase etc parameters with --unlock command via seal.

Example clique seal is here:

```
geth —-datadir <YOUR_GETH_INIT_PATH> --syncmode full --cache <CACHE_MEMORY> --networkid <GENESIS_NETWORK_ID> --port <DISCOVERABLE_MACHINE_PORT> --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock <MINER_PUBLIC_KEY> --password <YOUR_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD> 
--mine --snapshot=false --miner.etherbase <MINER_PUBLIC_KEY>
--ws --ws.port <YOUR_WS_PORT> --ws.origins "*" --ws.addr <WS_IP> --http.vhosts="*" --http --http.addr <YOUR_IP> --http.corsdomain "*" --http.port <YOUR_PORT> --http.api personal,eth,net,web3,txpool,miner,rpc,admin,debug
```

You can reach a solution by researching these parameters.

Parameters Source: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/command-line-options

Good luck.